# Customize ImageDataGenerator for stratified sampling on Multi-Labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on `multi-label classification` problem where my `large-scale` data is highly `imbalanced`. So, I need to apply `stratified sampling` with the intuition that my `ImageDataGenerator` proportionally sample data from `each class` in `every batch`. Any suggestion/solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question indeed.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no built-in multi-label stratification in `ImageDataGenerator()`.

I will suggest two possible approaches:

1. You could subclass a `Sequence()` class in order to be able to control exactly what you feed at each step in the network. You could override the `__getitem__()` method, and ensure that the data is sampled proportionally in each batch.
2. You could use an external library which preprocesses your data before you feed it to your network. In this way, you could preprocess the data and use `tf.data.Dataset()` pipeline to feed the data to your network.

An example for (2) is this one:

```
from iterstrat.ml_stratifiers import MultilabelStratifiedKFold
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [1,2], [3,4], [1,2], [3,4], [1,2], [3,4]])
y = np.array([[0,0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,1], [1,1], [1,1], [1,0], [1,0]])

mskf = MultilabelStratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

for train_index, test_index in mskf.split(X, y):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Comment: I went with option 1 and create a custom batch where samples from each class are added proportionally. But, my batch is not complete sometime, e.g. I have given batch_size 32 and selected 10 samples from each of 3 classes make total 30 (2 less than the batch_size). So, what is the best way to fill the batch with last 2 entry ? Should it be random or there is some other better way ?

Comment: Yes, it could be random, practically it's impossible if your batch_size is not divisible with the number of classes, it would be impossible to perfectly balance it.